# Spring security oauth 2 client app can't check token validity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

here is what I'm trying to achieve :

I have an enterprise oauth 2 provider, I want to use their login form and get code, access token and so on from this provider

here is my conf

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: MY_CLIENT_ID
      clientSecret: asecret
      accessTokenUri: https://blabla/oauth-server/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri:  https://blabla/oauth-server/oauth/authorize
      tokenName: access_token
      scope : read
      userInfoUri: https://localhost/user
```

I can get my code which is changed for an access token, everything is fine, it's calling my local endpoint to get user information (roles for instance)

but when I debug the code I can't see any expires_in value anywhere and my token doesn't expire at all.

here's my resource server conf

```
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@RestController
public class SecurityController extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "my_rest_api";


    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers().anyRequest().and().authorizeRequests();
        http.
                anonymous().disable()
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/**/*")
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**/*").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')")
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }
}
```

I can't fidn out how to revoke the token

any idea is welcome, i've lost a bunch of hour reading tutorials ...

Answer (score 0):

Add `access-token-validity-seconds` to your `yaml`

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: MY_CLIENT_ID
      clientSecret: asecret
      accessTokenUri: https://blabla/oauth-server/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri:  https://blabla/oauth-server/oauth/authorize
      tokenName: access_token
      scope : read
      userInfoUri: https://localhost/user
      access-token-validity-seconds: 30 //Adds 30 seconds of token validity
```

Comment: I coud but the token validity should be coming from auth provider right ?

Comment: I believe you are using an in-memory based client. You can update the access token validity for each client when you move the token-store to some database.

Comment: I'm using in memory store indeed but still, I get the expires_in value from the auth provider and this should be used and checked by Spring, no ? Or is there something I'm not understanding ?

Comment: Thats correct. The authorization server gives you the `expires_in` and later for each validated api request it first checks if the `access_token` has expired or not.

Comment: Seems that it does not check automatically this, neither it refreshes the token. sounds weird such a thing is not working

Comment: You mean your `access_token` never gets expired even if the auth server gives you an `expires_in`?

Comment: exactly, I added a filter to check the token and it is expired but I'm still authenticated :/

Comment: But if you are using `spring-security-oauth2` you don't have to explicitly validate the tokens. Validation of tokens are taken care by `spring-security-oauth2` itself. Check out this [tut](http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-oauth2/).

Comment: That's one of the many tut i tried, I'm indeed using spring-security-oauth2 and the validations of the token seem to be off

Comment: Mine is working pretty fine. Check out my [code](https://github.com/Abdullah8006/myapp-oracle.git). Also i believe you have configured the `URL's` you want to be oauth secured!!

Comment: I had a look on what you did, you're using yourself as a auth server and ressource server. it's not my case .. still it should work :/

Comment: Actually I'm not sure anymore if my security rule are applied on resources (i added my conf in question). I tried to check a non existing scope and I'm still able to access everything ... that's weird, can you see something wrong in the conf ?

Comment: I am unable to access a restricted resource from the config you provided which means its working fine at my end. Only oauth related urls are allowed like `/oauth/token`.